# Scanf with spaces does not read at all

Tags: c, scanf

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
    int i;
    char name[10],surname[10],id[12],dpart[20];
    printf("******** ID Documentation ***********\n\n\n");
    printf("1) What is your Name? \n");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("2) What is your Surname? \n");
    scanf("%s",&surname);
    printf("3) What is your ID Number \n");
    scanf("%s",&id);
    printf("4) What is your Department? \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",&dpart);
    system("CLS");
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){printf("*");}printf("\n");
    printf("|");
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");}
    printf("|");printf("\n");printf("|");
    for(i=0;i<14;i++){printf("%%");}
    printf(" STUDENT ID CARD ");for(i=0;i<17;i++){printf("%%");}printf("|\n");printf("|");
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");}
    printf("|\n");
    printf(" //////// NAME: %6s ",name);for(i=0;i<26;i++){printf("/");}printf(" \n|");for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("-");}printf("|\n");
    printf(" //////// SURNAME: %6s ",surname);for(i=0;i<23;i++){printf("/");}printf(" \n|");for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("-");}printf("|\n");
    printf(" //////// ID NUMVER: %11s ",id);for(i=0;i<16;i++){printf("/");}printf(" \n|");for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("-");}printf("|\n");
    printf(" //////// DEPARTMENT: %22s ",dpart);for(i=0;i<4;i++){printf("/");}printf(" \n|");for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("-");}printf("|\n");
    printf("|");
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");}
    printf("|");printf("\n");
    printf("|");
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");}
    printf("|");printf("\n");
    printf("|");
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");}
    printf("|");printf("\n");for(i=0;i<50;i++){printf("*");}
   }
```

I was helping one of my friends on his homework. We have to read the department data than display it on a id card, but when it comes to reading department, the program skips it and adds the value entered for id number to department. 
Ps: I know that using scanf() is a very bad work, but they didn't learned anything else so i cannot suggest using sscanf to him
And also don't care the messy code when writing out data, it works

Comment: **bad idea** ... and also don't care the messy code when showing it to people who might help you ...

Comment: the start is not messy, that's where i need help, the rest works, so that's why i don't care

Comment: Also changing from scanf to fgets does not change anything at all

Comment: @gkaykck: Then only post the section of code that has the problem!

Comment: @Oli, but then usually people here want to see the rest of the code, if it is related or not !

Comment: @gkaykck: They'll only ask to see it if the problem relies on it.

Comment: so i posted all of it, whats wrong with this?

Comment: Don't use the `&` operator when passing array arguments to `scanf()` for the `%s` or `%[` conversion specifiers; you'll wind up passing a pointer of the wrong type (`char (*)[N]` instead of `char *`), which will cause problems later on. Except when it is the operand of the `&` or `sizeof` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array, an array expression will have its type implicitly converted from "N-element array of T" to "pointer to T", and its value will be set to point to the first element in the array. It's not *the* problem, but it isn't helping.

Comment: @gkaykck: The problem is that when debugging a problem (or asking others to do so for you), you should always attempt to reduce it to the *minimal* amount of code that causes the problem.  You'll probably discover the bug in the process, and if not, it'll make it easier for others to read. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have an unconsumed newline in the input buffer. A space in the format string will consume zero or more whitespace characters, so you can fix the problem by changing this line to include a space before the `%` as shown:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",dpart);
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns the number of successful assignments. **USE THAT RETURN VALUE** (EDIT) **ON ALL SCANF CALLS**

```
/* ... */
printf("1) What is your Name? \n");
if (scanf("%s",&name) != 1) { /* error */ printf("error on line %d.\n", __LINE__); }
printf("2) What is your Surname? \n");
if (scanf("%s",&surname) != 1) { /* error */ printf("error on line %d.\n", __LINE__); }
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf("%s") generally takes a single word as input, you can get around this using

`scanf("%[^\n]s")`, which means that you will accept any character but \n as input.

If that's not working use fgets like bjskishore123 suggested.  He has an example of using it below.

Comment: I have using it already in the code, but it is not working, not working if i add the s in the end or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fgets instead of scanf to read spaces as well.

Here is the working program

```
 #include <stdio.h> 

int main(){ 
    int i; 
    char name[10],surname[10],id[12],dpart[20]; 
    char tmpBuf[3];
    printf("******** ID Documentation ***********\n\n\n"); 
    printf("1) What is your Name? \n"); 
    //scanf("%s",&name); 
    fgets(name,8,stdin);
    fgets(tmpBuf, 2, stdin);

    printf("2) What is your Surname? \n"); 
    //scanf("%s",&surname); 
    fgets(surname,9,stdin);
    fgets(tmpBuf, 2, stdin);

    printf("3) What is your ID Number \n"); 
    //scanf("%s",&id); 
    fgets(id,11,stdin);
    fgets(tmpBuf, 1, stdin);

    printf("4) What is your Department? \n"); 
    //scanf("%[^\n]",&dpart); 
    fgets(dpart,19,stdin);
    system("CLS"); 
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){printf("*");}printf("\n"); 
    printf("|"); 
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");} 
    printf("|");printf("\n");printf("|"); 
    for(i=0;i<14;i++){printf("%%");} 
    printf(" STUDENT ID CARD ");for(i=0;i<17;i++){printf("%%");}printf("|\n");printf("|"); 
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");} 
    printf("|\n"); 
    printf(" //////// NAME: %6s ",name);for(i=0;i<26;i++){printf("/");}printf(" \n|");for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("-");}printf("|\n"); 
    printf(" //////// SURNAME: %6s ",surname);for(i=0;i<23;i++){printf("/");}printf(" \n|");for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("-");}printf("|\n"); 
    printf(" //////// ID NUMVER: %11s ",id);for(i=0;i<16;i++){printf("/");}printf(" \n|");for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("-");}printf("|\n"); 
    printf(" //////// DEPARTMENT: %22s ",dpart);for(i=0;i<4;i++){printf("/");}printf(" \n|");for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("-");}printf("|\n"); 
    printf("|"); 
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");} 
    printf("|");printf("\n"); 
    printf("|"); 
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");} 
    printf("|");printf("\n"); 
    printf("|"); 
    for(i=0;i<48;i++){printf("%%");} 
    printf("|");printf("\n");for(i=0;i<50;i++){printf("*");} 
   }
```

Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: fflush is removed and fgets is used to remove characters in stdin. could you remove downvote ? :)